# How to save the console print statements to a text file in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, printing

How can I save the console print statements to an exported text file in Xcode ?
I want to save my last console printed statement in a exported log text file in my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function such as this:

```
func write(text: String, to fileNamed: String, folder: String = "SavedFiles") {
        guard let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first else { return }
        guard let writePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path).appendingPathComponent(folder) else { return }
        try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: writePath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
        let file = writePath.appendingPathComponent(fileNamed + ".txt")
        try? text.write(to: file, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
```

and in the command line search for the file that your designated `writePath` variable is going to give you. You can copy that file elsewhere if you want

Comment: Thank you, 

That's helped me to crate a file and save some texts in it,

But now I want to add all my printed logs in the console to be automatically saved in that text file, Any recommendations?